# Delayed animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

I want to delay an animation that slides an image in a li a-element. I had the idea, that I could go through every li element with a counter (i) and set a timeout with the animation to do: 1000 + i * 50

Unfortunately only the last li-element will be animated. Why is that?

```
li = $('nav ul li').get();
lic = li.length;

$('nav ul li a .icon').hide();

t = [];
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var obj = $('nav ul li')[i];

    t[i] = setTimeout(function() {
        $(obj).children('a').children('.icon').slideDown();
    }, 1000 + i * 50);

    delete obj;
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping an already jQuery object in another jQuery constructor?

Comment: To clarify things, `delete obj` will not do anything because `delete` will only remove properties, not variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fine:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ikihuw/2/edit)*

```
$('nav ul li a .icon').hide();

$('nav ul li').each(function( i ){       
    $(this).find('.icon').delay(i*300).slideDown();    
});
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - `$(this).find(".icon")` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and this is no a full code, and un-tested. Please borrow the logic from this..

```
$('nav ul li').each(function {
    $(this).find("a>.icon").hide();
    t[i] = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).find("a>.icon").slideDown();
    }, 1000 + i * 50);
});
```